# JPA many-to-many update

Tags: jpa, many-to-many

Just another one regarding many to many relationship in JPA. I have the following structure in my database:

```
 ______      ___________      _______
| user |    | user2item |    | item  |
|------|    |-----------|    |-------|
| id   |    | user_id   |    | id    |
| name |    | item_id   |    | name  |
 ------      -----------     | type  | 
                              -------
```

Now i want to update the assingment from one user to items of a given type. So unfortunately i can't simply do:

```
user.setItems(newItemList);
```

because it would remove the assignments to items of other types. In plain old SQL i would do:

```
DELETE FROM user2item WHERE user_id = ? AND item_id IN (SELECT id FROM item WHERE type=?);
INSERT INTO user2item (user_id, item_id) VALUES(?,?);
```

But as i'm using JPA with QueryDSL plain SQL is no option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to remove all the items of a given type from te list of items, and then add other items to this list.

```
List<Item> items = user.getItems();
for (Iterator<Item> it = items.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Item item = it.next();
    if (item.getType().equals(theType)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
items.addAll(newItemList);
```

Basic collection manipulation. You should probably encapsulate this logic into a method of the User entity.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - this is the way i just started to implement as a temporary workaround. But i thought there must be a more elegant way to do it using fancy JPA/QueryDSL features.

Answer (score 0):

If user2item is not available as an entity you need to express it via your domain model. Alternative solutions for your case are using Native queries with Querydsl JPA or using Native queries in string form.